# combine elements of list of lists with the same name

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 4 lists with the same name:

```
lst1 <- 
list(list(c(1,2,3)),list(c(7,8,9)),list(c(4,5,6)),list(c(10,11,12)))
names(lst1) <- c("a","b","a","b")
```

I want to combine the sub lists together (first "a" with second "a", first "b" with second "b":

```
result <- list(list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)),list(c(7,8,9,10,11,12)))
names(result) <- c("a","b")
```

I have tried multiple things, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you please give an example how the expected result should looks like? It would also be helpful to see what you tried so far.

Comment: The result is the example of what I would like it to look like.

Answer (score 4):

Since `lst1["a"]` isn't going to give us all the elements of `lst1` named `a`, we are going to need to work with `names(lst1)`. One base R approach would be

```
nm <- names(lst1)
result <- lapply(unique(nm), function(n) unname(unlist(lst1[nm %in% n])))
names(result) <- unique(nm)
result
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#
# $b
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant solution.

Comment: A `purrr` translation : `map(set_names(unique(names(lst1))), ~unlist(lst1[names(lst1)==.],use.names = FALSE))`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `unlist` first and then `split` the resulting vector.

```
vec <- unlist(lst1)
split(unname(vec), sub("\\d+$", "", names(vec)))
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$b
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Just group the elements with the same name and `unlist` them:

```
tapply(lst1,names(lst1),FUN=function(x) unname(unlist(x)))
```