# append each named element of one list to the same named elements of another list

Tags: r

This seems like a no-brainer to me, but I can't find a simple solution unfortunately. I want to append each named element of one list to the same named elements of another list - retaining named list structure. I am *not* looking for a hard coded solution. My approach below gives the right structure, but not the right names.

```r
ls1 <- list(a = list(1:3, 1:3), b = list(1:3, 1:3))
ls2 <- list(a = 4:6, b = 4:6)


# desised output
list(a = list(1:3, 1:3, 4:6), b = list(1:3, 1:3, 4:6))
#> $a
#> $a[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $a[[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $a[[3]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b[[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b[[3]]
#> [1] 4 5 6

# my attempt
lapply(names(ls1), function(name) c(ls1[[name]], ls2[name]))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[1]]$a
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I was going to delete this question, but I decided to keep it for future searchers of similar problems.

Comment: also, somehow related - although I get the feeling that one doesn't need this overkill with purrr::reduce in my case https://stackoverflow.com/q/60884420/7941188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
Map(function(x, y) c(x, list(y)), ls1, ls2[names(ls1)])

#$a
#$a[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$a[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$a[[3]]
#[1] 4 5 6


#$b
#$b[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b[[3]]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `for` loop

```
for(nm in names(ls2)) ls1[[nm]] <- c(ls1[[nm]], list(ls2[[nm]]))
```

-output

```
ls1
#$a
#$a[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$a[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$a[[3]]
#[1] 4 5 6


#$b
#$b[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b[[3]]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is simply to use `setNames`. However, this still gives not quite the names I am looking for.

```
setNames(lapply(names(ls1), function(name) c(ls1[[name]], ls2[name])), names(ls1))
#> $a
#> $a[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $a[[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $a$a
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b[[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
```