# reorganize nested lists by element names: all elements with the same name together

Tags: r, matrix, nested-lists

I want to reorganize the grand list of `dlist4` in such a way that all the `a`'s stay in one nested list and all the `b`'s in another nested list.

```
A = list(a = matrix(1:4, 2), b = matrix(2:5, 2))

G = list(a = matrix(10:13, 2), b = matrix(5:8, 2))

M_1 = list(a = matrix(10:13, 2), b = matrix(5:8, 2))

M_2 = list(a = matrix(2:5, 2), b = matrix(5:8, 2))

dlist4 <- tibble::lst(A, G, M_1, M_2)
```

The answers from these questions: [R list - combine elements with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020599/r-list-combine-elements-with-same-name) and [combine elements of list of lists with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172630/combine-elements-of-list-of-lists-with-the-same-name) got me close. I need the list structure to I removed the `unlist()`, but this result is unexpected.

```
tapply(dlist4,names(dlist4), FUN=function(x) unname(x))
$A
$A$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$A$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5


$G
$G$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   12
[2,]   11   13

$G$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8


$M_1
$M_1$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   12
[2,]   11   13

$M_1$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8


$M_2
$M_2$a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5

$M_2$b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

I need a list of `a` that has four elements, `a$A`, `a$G`, `a$M_1`, and `a$M_2`, and the same with a list of `b`; and then `a` and `b` nested in a bigger list.  Thanks so much for any hints.

Comment: I'm not certain of the output required, but does `lapply(c("a","b"), \(x) lapply(dlist4, \`[\`, x) )` do it?

Comment: Sounds like you want to transpose the list - `purrr::transpose(dlist4)`.

Comment: Yes, `transpose` is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
do.call(rlist::list.zip, dlist4)
```

or

```r
purrr::lift(rlist::list.zip)(dlist4)
```

?

```r
$a
$a$A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$a$G
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   12
[2,]   11   13

$a$M_1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   12
[2,]   11   13

$a$M_2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5


$b
$b$A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5

$b$G
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

$b$M_1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

$b$M_2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Comment: I think that's the right result, but would it be order dependent on the pattern always being a-then-b in each list? Similar base option I think - `do.call(Map, c(list, dlist4))`